# Unable to login with MD5 encypted password in core php

Tags: php, authentication, phpmyadmin, md5

I want to login with saved credentials in user table using core php, my password is saved in encrypted form in MD5 in database user table, i want to login with email and password, but when i encrypted my password while login password do not match with database table password,
please help me, how can i login with encrypted md5 password. here is my code.

index.html

```
     <form action="login_admin.php" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Username</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email">
                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                            </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Password</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="*********" name="pwd">
                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                <span class="input-group-text">
                              <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                            </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn btn-block">
                                   
                                </form>
```

login_admin.php

```
<?php

    include('connection.php');
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['pwd'];
        $password = md5($_POST['pwd']);
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $admin= $_SESSION['email'];
    
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` Where (email = '$email' && role_id = 'admin' )";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($row > 0){
                if($admin == $row['email'] && $password == $row['password']){
                    echo "test"; die;
                }
        }
    
    else{
        echo "Login Failed";
    }
    
    ?>
```

connection.php

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "example_user";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }   
    ?>
```

Comment: md5 is not encryption... So there is nothing can be done with "md5-**encrypted**" anything.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov where is my mistake?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov my login md5 password and md5 password from database table both are different that's why i am not able to login. that's what mistake in my code.

Comment: @ParteekKumar MD5 For all languages is now broken, meaning its not safe. use password_hash / password_verify for this .Its by php and you can Pass many types of hashes like PASSWORD_BYCRIPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to Unhash a Password?

> Read my comment First.

---

### To hash

```
 password_hash ( string $password , mixed $algo , array $options = ? ) : string|false
```

Usage :

```
<?php echo password_hash('Hello world', PASSWORD_BCRYPT ) ?>
```

Values:
$password = "password";;
$algo = "password algorithm";

For more info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php

### Compare a password with a hashed version##

```
  password_verify ( string $password , string $hash ) : bool
```

Usage :

```
<?php $text = "I am a php master!"; $hashed = password_hash($text, PASSWORD_BYCRIPT); echo $text . "<br>". $hashed . "<br>";
   // password_verify returns a Boolean
   if(password_Verify($text, $hashed)) echo "Correct";   
  ?>
```

Values:

password

```
The user's password.
```

hash

```
A hash created by password_hash().
```

For more info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: `password_verify` does not “unhash” anything (because that is technically impossible), it _compares_ two hashes for equality.